# Fetching href element only from the element XPath in Selenium + Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

The application I am testing searches for an account based on the email ID. The email ID is unique. The result gets displayed in the form of a table with various columns. One of which is "Account Name" displaying the name of the user/account holder linked to the email address in question. In order to go into the account, one has to click on this "Account Name" value which is a link. This "Account Name" link is dynamic based on the email ID we use every time. On inspecting this link I get this:

```html
<a href="/001m000000pFY6U?srPos=0&amp;srKp=001" data-seclke="Account" data-seclkh="60761f49cf4ed8788252c560b733bef0" data- seclki="001m000000pFY6U" data-seclkp="/001m000000pFY6U" data-seclkr="1" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)" xpath="1" style="">F John</a>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to retrieve/extract only the 
    `href="/001m000000pFY6U?srPos=0&amp;srKp=001"` bit from the above.

I tried the following:

```
elem = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
print(elem)
```

and this prints 120 lines something similar to the following:
    selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
    (session="502b43c903be36c997d4882f26f3c7ad",element="0.4252537892711272- 
    1")

Would appreciate a little help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dan can you share the full output of the href's as in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following line of code:

```
account_links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[data-seclke='Account']")]
```

where `account_links` will be a list of your needed links.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you Ratmir Asanov. It worked and returned a list and the second element at index 1, is what I need. See this:

['https://cs20.salesforce.com/01m000000TpFY6U/e?srPos=0&srKp=001&retURL=%2Fsearch%2FSearchResult%3FsearchType%3D1%26sen%3D0011%26setLast%3D1%26sbstr%3Drugbyfff%2540yahoo.co.uk%26search%3D%2Bo0o%2521%2B', 'https://cs20.salesforce.com/001m000000pTY6U?srPos=0&srKp=001', 'mailto:rugbyfan@yahoo.co.uk']

Answer (score 0):

You should use `get_attribute`.

For example:

```
elems = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for i in elems:
     print(i.get_attribute("href")
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks Moshe Slavin for your response. However I tried that as well but it prints 124 lines of some javascript code like:
  javascript:openPopupFocusEscapePounds(%27https://help.salesforce.com/apex/htdoor?loc=help&target=search_refine_a.htm&section=Search&language=en_US&release=218.6.2&instance=CS20&showSplash=true%27, %27Help%27, 1024, 768, %27width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,directories=no,location=yes,dependant=no%27, false, false);
    javascript:openPopupFocusEscapePounds(%27https://help.salesforce.com/apex/

Comment: Hi @DanSmith, can you share the full html anchor tag line of the above output?

Comment: <a href="/001m000000pFY6U?srPos=0&amp;srKp=001" data-seclke="Account" data-seclkh="60761f49cf4ed8788252c560b733bef0" data-seclki="001m000000pFY6U" data-seclkp="/001m000000pFY6U" data-seclkr="1" onmousedown="searchResultClick.mousedown(this, event)">F Chau</a>

Thanks @Ali

Comment: Try this `elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a")
for i in elements:
    print i.get_attribute('href')`, I have posted the answer

Comment: @DanSmith, The XPath for finding the anchor tags

Comment: @DanSmith, what output are you getting?

Comment: Hi @Moshe Slavin, XPath for finding the anchor tag 'a' I have changed

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a")
for i in elements:
    print i.get_attribute('href')
```

'a' will identify all the anchors then by using the attribute 'href', we can get the links.

Comment: No Ali CSE it does not.. Returns a lot of entries as mentioned earlier. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.Check if works

```
  shref=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-seclke="Account"]').get_attribute("href")
    print(shref)
```

Comment: Thanks Kajal. It returns one entry now which I can use to navigate to the account. However that is not what I want I want to click on the Account name link in the table (as mentioned in my original post) and then go into the account.